# What do I have to do in order to Install Windows 8 os via USB when I already have Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop?

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, windows-8, iso

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10(The latest version) onto my laptop from a USB. Now, I want to completely erase Ubuntu 13.10 and go back to Windows 8. Is there anything special I have to do besides put a Windows 8 ISO onto a USB and boot it through BIOS? Do I have to reset anything in BIOS?

My computer is a Asus G46V if that helps.

I'm not trying to make this hard on anyone lol I'm just a beginner at installing new OS's. I was proud of myself for installing Ubuntu though. Works like a charm. I play league of legends(a game on windows) and I didn't like the fps(frames per second) Ubuntu offered so that is the reason I want to switch back.

Last note: The usb I use is 4 GB. Although, as you'll probably know, I only have 3.7GB due to the conversion or whatever.

Thanks for all who help :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like graphic card driver issues, which you could enquire about, but their is this: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller#A2nd_option_%3a_install_OS-Uninstaller_in_Ubuntu)

but I do not now whether it works, especially if you have a dual boot setup (which if you have not considered, means you could run both operating systems, Windows for games, Ubuntu for other stuff.

Comment: OS-Uninstaller allows to remove an OS only if there are at least 2 operating systems available.

Answer (score 0):

To replace Ubuntu by Windows, you don't need to reset anything in your BIOS, but just need to erase your disk (eg via [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted)), then install Windows on the blank disk.

As an alternative, you can also install Windows besides Ubuntu (by shrinking the Ubuntu partition via Gparted, then install Windows in the free space).